# Snake game (fading food)

Tags: c#, class, random, timer

I have simple snake game. There is snake and one random food. But i want another one food  , but this food will by time limited. For example: When snake reaches 20points , it generate bonus time limited food. This food will be displayed for 5 seconds (for example). How i can do it?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random randFood = new Random();

        private had _model;
        Graphics paper;
        had snakes = new had();
        kocky food;
        bool left = false;
        bool right = false;
        bool up = false;
        bool down = false;
        int score = 0;
        kocky1 food1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            food = new kocky(randFood);
            food1 = new kocky1(randFood);  //time limited food//
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            paper = e.Graphics;
            food.drawFood(paper);
            food1.drawFood(paper);         
            snakes.drawSnake(paper);    
        }
//---------------------------program----------------------------------------------------//

 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            snakeScoreLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
            if (down) { snakes.moveDown(); }
            if (up) { snakes.moveUp(); }
            if (right) { snakes.moveRight(); }
            if (left) { snakes.moveLeft(); }
            this.Invalidate();
            collision();
            for (int i = 0; i < snakes.SnakeRec.Length; i++)
            {
                if (snakes.SnakeRec[i].IntersectsWith(food.foodRec))
                {
                    WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
                    wplayer.URL = "C:\\Users\\Boris\\Desktop\\C# had\\SNOTPLOP.wav";
                    wplayer.controls.play(); 
                    timer1.Enabled = true;
                    score += 1;
                    ProgressBar1.Increment(1);
                    snakes.growSnake();
                    food.foodlocation(randFood);
                    food1.foodlocation(randFood);
                }
            if (snakes.SnakeRec[i].IntersectsWith(food1.foodRec))  //time limited food//
                {
                    WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
                    wplayer.URL = "C:\\Users\\Boris\\Desktop\\C# had\\SNOTPLOP.wav";
                    wplayer.controls.play();
                    timer1.Enabled = true;
                    score += 1;
                    ProgressBar1.Increment(1);
                    snakes.growSnake();
                    food.foodlocation(randFood);
                    food1.foodlocation(randFood);
                }
```

Comment: "How i can do it?" - Where are you stuck?

Comment: The first thing I would do if I were you is to actually try to solve the problem yourself. Think through what you want to happen, then slap some code in an editor that tries to achieve those goals. If it doesn't work, *then* come on SO and post a question, with the code that didn't work, and what you expected it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your time limited food could have an int duration, which gets decreased by the timer, and deletes itself on 0.

Answer (score 0):

well first of all the special food you want to create called "Power up". 
the way that you can create this . as much as you hold snack blocks array you hold array of food that can be of length of 1

each food has its own state: Normal,Special.

when creating a food set a timestamp or other indication of creation time (like ticks)
then when you've reach number of life seconds you can kill the food instance and remove it from the screen